# sdo_aggr_union is not working

Tags: geoserver, spatial-database, oracle-spatial

I have a table `map_building_data` and I create view `all_incidents_unions`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ALL_INCIDENTS_UNIONS
(
   ORA_GEOMETRY
)
AS
SELECT sdo_aggr_union (MDSYS.sdoaggrtype (ora_geometry, 0.005))
             ora_geometry
       FROM (  SELECT sdo_aggr_union (MDSYS.sdoaggrtype (ora_geometry, 0.005))
                         ora_geometry
                 FROM (  SELECT sdo_aggr_union (
                                   MDSYS.sdoaggrtype (ora_geometry, 0.005))
                                   ora_geometry
                           FROM (  SELECT sdo_aggr_union (
                                             MDSYS.sdoaggrtype (ora_geometry, 0.005))
                                             ora_geometry
                                     FROM (  SELECT sdo_aggr_union (
                                                       MDSYS.sdoaggrtype (ora_geometry,
                                                                          0.005))
                                                       ora_geometry
                                               FROM (  SELECT sdo_aggr_union (
                                                                 MDSYS.sdoaggrtype (
                                                                    ora_geometry,
                                                                    0.005))
                                                                 ora_geometry
                                                         FROM (  SELECT SDO_AGGR_UNION (
                                                                           SDOAGGRTYPE (
                                                                              COM.GEOM,
                                                                              0.005))
                                                                           ora_geometry
                                                                   FROM MAP_BUILDING_DATA COM
                                                                  WHERE ID =9307433
                                                               GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 128))
                                                     GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 64))
                                           GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 32))
                                 GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 16))
                       GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 8))
             GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 4))
   GROUP BY MOD (ROWNUM, 2));
```

After create view I am inserting data on `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA`

```
INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DIMINFO,SRID)VALUES ('ALL_INCIDENTS_UNIONS','ORA_GEOMETRY',MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X',8255000,8754700,0.005),MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y',4261000,4614700,0.005)),'2400000');
```

After this when I create layer on **geoserver** and want see result, this return error

```
Rendering process failed java.io.IOExceptionORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 1224
```

please help ..........

Comment: Could you edit the title to describe your real problem?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says "interface not supported without a spatial index" - so you need to add a spatial index to your view.

I don't use Oracle if I can help it but I think you will need to make a materialised view for this.

Comment: view don't having spatial index, but I add `INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DIMINFO,SRID)VALUES ('ALL_INCIDENTS_UNIONS','ORA_GEOMETRY',MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X',8255000,8754700,0.005),MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y',4261000,4614700,0.005)),'2400000');`

Comment: problem is `sdo_aggr_union`

Comment: if it needs a spatial index to work then that is indeed the problem until you create a spatial index. Or you could switch to postgis

Comment: As you can see the message comes from Oracle. It can't handle the spatial SQL query that GeoServer sends (probably with bbox filter). It is understandable that Oracle can't use spatial index because the geometry is created on-the-fly as an aggregate. Materialize the view, create spatial index, and it should work. I am not sure how well PostGIS could handle such aggregates with spatial queries.

Comment: I created materialized view, its working, but it is not dynamic, when I add new data, materialized view not have this row

Comment: Make a trigger that updates your materialized view on inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: Some materialized views are automatically updated (meaning at set intervals), but a complex view like this one will not. Then again computing an aggregation is expensive, which I assume is why you use the complex technique of recursive construction.  That approach is no longer needed in 12.1 provided you are licensed for Oracle Spatial (which then entitles you to enable the "spatial vector acceleration" feature).

Comment: As for this business of spatial index and views, the solution is to define a function-based index, i.e. a spatial index on the result of the aggregation function. However that function is too complicated in your case. A simple aggregation would be possible.